# MFT Audio fadeout effect

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation

I'm writing Windows Phone C# application and I need some custom effects, which are done by MFT (Media Foundation Transform).

I know C++ just a little, so I would need an advice how to start with implementing some effect, for example audio fadeout.

Comment: Probably too late now, but I've got some c++ and c# examples of how to write MFTs, along with templates to make it easier, and extensive docs at http://www.LimeGreenSocks.com/MFT

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your samples, but I think it's not my cup of tea :) Would you be interested in helping me port my existing video app to Windows 10 from Windows Phone? Or can you recommend me someone, who know MFT?